# Defining the Linear Programming Model for TSP with multi access per point

Tags: pulp, traveling-salesman

I am trying to use pulp to solve a TSP (similar to this:

[Defining the Linear Programming Model for Traveling Salesman in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39888448/defining-the-linear-programming-model-for-traveling-salesman-in-python)

https://www.kaggle.com/itoeiji/solving-tsp-and-vrp-by-mip-using-pulp)

However, instead of going through all the points, some of the points have different access and only one access per point is enough. We can imagine a postman delivering n houses with some of the houses (m houses) having 2 letter boxes, one in the north and one in the south.

Example:
We can consider 5 points, with point 2 and 3 having 2 letter boxes.

Some potential solutions of the problem would be:

- [1, 2S, 3N, 4, 5]
- [1, 2N, 3S, 4, 5]
- [1, 2S, 3S, 4, 5]
- etc...

Any ideas how to modify the constraints in order to tackle this variation?

Comment: I would think that you could pre-process this and group houses locations with "2 letter boxes" to be equivalent to a substitute as in `2*` represents `2N` and `2S` and solve.  If it is the case that the geography implies that the actual routing is different between the 2 points *and* you need to capture that in your model, you are going to have to set up a bunch of "or" constraints for the pairs, which isn't too hard, but adds complexity & solve time

Comment: This is actually what I did. It works but adds complexity and time as you mentioned.